# Avoiding unexistent metadata in Perforce Server

Tags: metadata, perforce

My question might be simple, and the solution as well, however, i want to know, supposing that a user syncs a branch, and later delete the physical files from his local machine manually, the metadata about these files wil still exist in the server...

In the long run i'm afraid this could slow down the server.

I haven't found much about this issue, this is why i'm asking here, how do companies usually manage their Perforce metadata? A trigger that verifies the existing metadatas? a program that runs `sync #none` for client directories that does not exist anymore from time to time?

As i said, there might be many simple ways to solve that, but i'm looking for the best one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice I don't think you'll have too much to worry about.

That being said, if you want to keep the workspace metadata size to a minimum, there are two things you'll need to do:

1. You'll need to write the `sync #none` script you referenced above, and also make sure to delete any workspaces that are no longer in use.
2. Create a checkpoint, and recreate the metadata from that checkpoint. When the metadata is recreated, that should remove any data from deleted clients. My understanding of the Perforce metadata is that it won't shrink unless it's being recreated from a checkpoint.

Comment: That's my understanding. The only way to shrink the metadata is to recreate it. Also, along the lines of controlling metadata size, it's good practice to limit workspaces to only include the minimum set of what they need.

Comment: Always thought that by syncing revisions to 0 the server would lose its information, since there is no 0 revision. If it doesn't shrink, then i wonder whats the sense of syncing revisions to `#none`, the user can always delete the files phisically or then force a sync with `sync -f`... But its ok, thank you very much for your help. :)